# Consulta MySql não conclui a busca de todos os campos BLOB

Tags: query, sql-select, blob

Boa tarde.

Estou com um problema que eu não sei bem o que é. O que acontece é que eu tenho uma lista de clientes e cada cliente tem uma foto de cadastro.(Está em torno de 2000 clientes)

Na minha aplicação eu faço 2 tipos de backup, 1 deles é buscando todos os dados manualmente e serializando eles em um arquivo, e o segundo é utilizando o proprio SGBD.

Voltando ao problema, quando eu peço "select * clientes", a busca simplesmente não me traz o resultado. Imaginei que fosse por conta do tamanho do banco que esta em quase 300 MB e a aplicação é em rede, então eu fiz a busca dos dados sem a foto do cadastro e depois busquei foto por foto e também não deu certo, a aplicação começa a trazer, porém quando chega um pouco mais da metade simplesmente para de me trazer resultados mas não da nenhuma exception, consigo mexer nos botoes normalmente, então não sei o que pode estar acontecendo muito menos o que posso fazer pra corrigir esse problema.

Resumindo, eu faço a pesquisa de dados BLOB e se eu peço pra trazer todos de uma vez a aplicação fica horas e horas e horas eu nunca traz o resultado, e se eu peço pra trazer 1 por 1, a aplicação traz até pouco mais da metade e simplesmente para de fazer a pesquisa e nem vai pra frente nem pra traz no código.

Lembrando que é uma aplicação em rede, quando eu executo em maquina local funciona tudo perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

O que acontecia é que a JVM estava cheia e não aguentava mais trazer dados.

Pra resolver eu criei um arquivo .vbs pra pra executar o .jar utilizando o parâmetro pra aumentar a capacidade da JVM.

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "Java -jar -Xmx2048M  arquivo.jar", 0

porém quando executei em outra maquina, o arquivo não abriu, então eu executei apenas "Java -jar -Xmx2048M  arquivo.jar" no próprio comand prompt do windows e apareceu um erro dizendo que não poderia alocar 2048 MB pra JVM, então só reduzi o tamanho e funcionou.